# While loop syntax error in script using c shell

Tags: shell, unix, csh

I'm trying to print the square numbers that are less than a number the user inputs. If the number is greater than 1000 then a error message shows. The problem Im having with my code is that the wile loop seems to have a syntax error but I cannot find the syntax error after multiple attempts.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
#! /bin/csh -f

set Square = 0

echo "Please enter a number smaller than 1000"
set num = $<
if ($num > 1000) then
  echo "The number is invalid"
  exit 1
else
echo "Square number for 1 to $num"
set i = 1
while ($i <= num)
  set Square = `$i * $i`
  echo $Square
  @ i++
end
endif
```

If I entered a dummy nnumber like 455.

```
Error:
455
Square number for 1 to 455
while: Expression Syntax.
```

Answer (score 1):

using an `expr` should fix this, as well as adding a `$` to `num`:

```bash
#! /bin/csh -f

set Square = 0

echo "Please enter a number smaller than 1000"
set num = $<
if ($num > 1000) then
  echo "The number is invalid"
  exit 1
else
echo "Square number for 1 to $num"
set i = 1
while ( $i <= $num )
  set Square = `expr $i \* $i`
  echo $Square
  @ i++
end
endif
```

Comment: That fixes only one of several problem in the script. You also made one other change to the code that you didn't mention (`num` --> `$num`). Finally, there's no need to use the external `expr` command; csh has built-in expression evaluation with `@`.

Comment: I *did* mention the change to `$num`. But what other part of the problem does this not fix?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your script.

You're trying to compare `$i` to `num` (a string) rather than to `$num`.

You can use `@` to evaluate an arithmetic expression, for example `@ x = 2 + 2` sets `$x` to `4`; applying that is left as an exercise. Enclosing an arithmetic expression in backticks doesn't work; it tries to execute the enclosed text as a command, and expands to the command's output.

Your loop condition is incorrect. If the user enters `500`, you'll print 500 lines of output.

(csh is not a good language for programming. Consider learning sh or one of its relatives, such as ksh, bash, or zsh.)